# WPF Wired Event Handler is not called

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, user-controls, .net-3.5

Day 2 and I don't have a clue.  [.Net 3.5, VS 2008]

I have a `UserControl` that defines a `ClickEvent`:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent ClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent (
  "Click", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof ( RoutedEventHandler ), typeof ( TouchToggleButton ) );
```

and an `OnClick` method:

```
protected virtual void OnClick ( )
{
    RaiseEvent ( new RoutedEventArgs { RoutedEvent = ClickEvent, Source = this } );
}
```

In each of two different windows, I wire an instance of this control to an event handler.

```
<wft:TouchToggleButton DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="measurableButton" Click="measurableButton_Click">Cannot Measure</wft:TouchToggleButton>
```

and

```
<wft:TouchToggleButton x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="BuyoutButton" Click="BuyoutButton_Click">Buyout</wft:TouchToggleButton>
```

and, finally, I have the two handlers defined:

```
private void measurableButton_Click ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    IsMeasurable = !IsMeasurable;
    OnMeasurableButtonChanged ( );
}
```

and

```
private void BuyoutButton_Click ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    IsBuyout = !IsBuyout;
    OnBuyoutButtonChanged ( );
}
```

In both cases, if I put a breakpoint at the `OnClick`, it hits.  In the case of the measurableButton, the `RaiseEvent` goes to measurableButton_Click; in the case of the BuyoutButton, the RaiseEvent does NOT go to BuyoutButton_Click.

There is nowhere in the app an unwiring (-=) of the BuyoutButton.Click.  What further could I check to discover the reason for the difference in these behaviors?

Comment: The only difference I see in the buttons is one has `x:FieldModifier` and the other doesn't. Does it work if you remove it? Also, does it work the opposite if you switch the button positions? I can't see your full UserControl code, but it's possible that you're overwriting the ClickEvent when setting the 2nd event, rather than creating a new instance of the event.

Comment: Removing `x:FieldModifier` does not change the behavior.  I cannot switch the button positions, they are in two completely different windows.  Is it even possible to overwrite the ClickEvent with `Click="method"` syntax? (I am new to WPF, but aren't these still multicast delegates?)

Comment: My UserControl is derived from another; the base class defines the `public event RoutedEventHandler Click`.  I did not realize that I had to have the exact same code in the derived class (why wouldn't it inherit?), but when I added the event to the derived class, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to Rachel for making me think about the event, I realized I had left out

```
public event RoutedEventHandler Click
{
    add { AddHandler ( ClickEvent, value ); }
    remove { RemoveHandler ( ClickEvent, value ); }
}
```

in my inherited class.  (Being an event, it does not inherit.)  This fixed my problem, although I still wonder how it ever worked in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't help you understand how to do what you asked, but I have a suggestion anyway in case this turns out to be an XYZ problem.

Just from looking at what you're doing, which is toggling Boolean values with a more or less custom implementation of a Button, I would suggest using a `ToggleButton` instead. It would be a more WPF-ey way to do it.

That way the state is clear in the UI, you don't have to hook up the logic, the toggling is handled for you, and you can bind to the `IsChecked` value!

Anyways, my two cents' worth.